# Wordpress term list of a post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In Wordpress I am building an index page where I list in a table all the articles of my blog. Every row of this table has the following structure: post title, terms belonging to a certain group. For example, if it were about movies:

```
 Blade Runner       | noir, science fiction
 Gone with the Wind | dramatic
```

The point is: when I have multiple terms there is some weird error that returns an empty set or sometimes the wrong terms are listed. And I am quite puzzled because I can't figure out why this happens. This is how I fetch the data.

```
//Loops through the articles in the table wp_posts
foreach($results as $result){
    $metaStr = "";
    $id = $result->ID;
    $query = "
        SELECT name 
        FROM wp_term_relationships 
        INNER JOIN wp_terms
        ON term_id = term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE object_id = $id AND term_taxonomy_id IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 18, 22, 24, 30)
    ";
    $metas = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $count = 0;
    foreach($metas as $meta){
        if($count > 0){
            $metaStr .= "<br />";
        }
        $metaStr .= $meta->name;
        $count++;
    }
    print $metaStr;
}
```

Anybody can help? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?
Cheers

Comment: What are you doing wrong? That's easy. See normalisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following function and just pass the post id, In your case $result->ID;

```
function my_get_term_of_post($postId){
$metaStr="";
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($postId, 'console', array("fields" => "all"));
$i=1;
foreach($term_list as $termSingle){
    if($i==1)
     $metaStr=$termSingle->name;
    else
     $metaStr.= "<br/>".$termSingle->name;
    $i++;
}
return $metaStr;
```

}

$term_list= my_get_term_of_post($result->ID);

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to change 'console' with 'post_tag' (the default). Otherwise I was getting an invalid taxonomy error.

Answer (score 0):

### Never store multiple values in a single column!

Rather change your table design and add another table for the mapping. Like

```
posts table
------------
id
title


tags table
------------
id
name


post_tags table
------------------
post_id
tag_id
```

That way you will have a defined list of tags, a fast way to query the data and it is normalized too.

Comment: I am talking about the standard wordpress wp_terms table. It's a many-to-many relationship.